# Django error: too many open files

Tags: python, django, anaconda

I'm using Anaconda python and I'm trying to run a simple Django server using the official documentation. When I run `python manage.py runserver` I get this error

```
Nuseirs-MacBook-Pro:anothertry nyassin$ python manage.py runserver
Validating models...

0 errors found
November 06, 2013 - 18:27:10
Django version 1.7.dev20131105182658, using settings 'anothertry.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/nyassin/django-trunk/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 416, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/nyassin/django-trunk/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 408, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/nyassin/django-trunk/django/core/management/base.py", line 244, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/Users/nyassin/django-trunk/django/core/management/base.py", line 291, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/nyassin/django-trunk/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 76, in handle
    self.run(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/nyassin/django-trunk/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 85, in run
    autoreload.main(self.inner_run, args, options)
  File "/Users/nyassin/django-trunk/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 359, in main
    reloader(wrapped_main_func, args, kwargs)
  File "/Users/nyassin/django-trunk/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 325, in python_reloader
    reloader_thread()
  File "/Users/nyassin/django-trunk/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 304, in reloader_thread
    if fn():
  File "/Users/nyassin/django-trunk/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 217, in kqueue_code_changed
    new_descriptors = set(open(filename) for filename in new_filenames)
  File "/Users/nyassin/django-trunk/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 217, in <genexpr>
    new_descriptors = set(open(filename) for filename in new_filenames)
IOError: [Errno 24] Too many open files: '//anaconda/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/resource.so'
```

Any ideas what might be causing this?

Comment: use `ps -ef | grep manage` to see if there are any django processes from before ?

Comment: You can also just restart your computer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an operating system error. The maximum number of open files is limited. Try to find where you open files and forget to close them.

Open less file descriptors at once.

```
set(open(filename) for filename in new_filenames)
```

is where the error occurs.

Comment: Yea I think is most likely an error with Anaconda. I will try to run django from a virtual environment instead. Thanks!